# How to split a string to identical parts without a giving pattern?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a function that returns every time a different string but with a specific random pattern, this pattern could be as simple as "a, b, c, **a, b, c**" or something much more complicated.

So what I need is to write a function that searches in the string for a pattern and return it.

There is only one condition to be considered, let's say we have this string for example: "a, b, a, b, c, a, b, a, b, c"

In that string you can't say that "a, b" is a pattern, to consider a specific string as a pattern then it should be longer than the remaining string, in that case, "a,b" is (2 digits * 2) = 4 and the remaining is "c, a, b, a, b, c" 6 digits, so what consider a real pattern is "a, b, a, b, c".

I was about writing a function to do that but I know it's going to be a complicated one so I thought to ask SO before if maybe there is a built-in functionality in PHP or Javascript which can do something close from that or makes the job easier for me, so any ideas guys?

Comment: Appreciate the question, however I personally believe you may have done this slightly out of order. Before asking SO for help, I'd suggest taking a shot at writing the function, and if you get into the weeds, ask for some help! If you get it working but want to improve it, drop it over in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). Good luck!

Comment: @TylerRoper, why in Code Review not in here, what is it different from here?

Comment: @Tarek.hms StackOverflow is for code that you're trying to fix, or resolving specific problems. If your code is working perfectly and you're just looking to improve how it's written, then you'd post it at Code Review.

Comment: @TylerRoper, I see, thanks, I didn't know that before.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand the rules. Could you give some more examples?

Comment: @Nick, It was difficult even to me to explain it and yet I didn't cover the whole problem in the question, but simply what I'm looking for is the longest pattern in a string, another example would be like: a,a,b,b,c , a,a,b,b,c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a regexp: `^([a-z]{2,})(?:\1)+$`. The regex uses a recursive pattern to match any string that has a repeating pattern, placing the pattern in the first group. This is how to use it in PHP:

**Edit**

The regex has been updated to allow an incomplete pattern on the end (as long as there has been one repeat) and then that is checked that it matches for its length against the pattern, to allow matching strings such as `abcabca`.

```
function check_match($string) {
    if (preg_match('/^([a-z]{2,})(?:\1)+(.*)$/', $string, $matches)) {
        return strlen($matches[2]) == 0 || $matches[2] == substr($matches[1], 0, strlen($matches[2])) ? $matches[1] : false;
    }
    return false;

}

foreach (array("abca", "abcabcab", "abcabcabcabc", "ababcababc", "aabbaabb", "aabaab", "aabaabd", "abcd", "aabcaabc", "abcabca") as $str) {
    if ($pattern = check_match($str))
        echo "$str matched $pattern\n";
    else 
        echo "no pattern for $str\n";
}
```

Output:

```
no pattern for abca
abcabcab matched abc
abcabcabcabc matched abcabc
ababcababc matched ababc
aabbaabb matched aabb
aabaab matched aab
no pattern for aabaabd
no pattern for abcd
aabcaabc matched aabc
abcabca matched abc
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, I'm confused now who should I choose as an answer, but yet as I mentioned to CertainPerformance, this code also works but only if the whole string contains complete patterns but if the last part of the string, which is a case sometimes, was incomplete then this function will fail, if you could adjust it to return a match even in that case then the answer is yours.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? Something like `abca` or does it have to be `abcabca`?

Comment: abcabcab, here the last two characters are missing a 'c' to complete the pattern but yet it shouldn't be a problem since the pattern repeated before and it's longer than the remaining string.

Comment: Try my new code. The regex has been updated to allow an incomplete pattern on the end (as long as there has been one repeat) and then that is checked that it matches for its length against the pattern.

Comment: Yup, that's it, I think I will go with the regex, it's always more efficient, and that's too is really impressive, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the simplest solution would be to start from the beginning of the string and find the smallest substring starting from index 0 such that repeating that substring some number of times results in the input string:

```js
const findPattern = str => {
  const { length } = str;
  for (let i = 1; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
    const testPattern = str.slice(0, i);
    const repeats = Math.ceil(length / i);
    if (str === testPattern.repeat(repeats).slice(0, length)) return testPattern;
  }
  return 'No pattern found';
}
console.log(findPattern('ababcababc'));
console.log(findPattern('aabbaabb'));
console.log(findPattern('aabaab'));
console.log(findPattern('aabaabaab'));
console.log(findPattern('abcdabc'));
console.log(findPattern('abcd'));
```

Comment: Wow, that was really fast, I have should probably give a try before posting a question, anyway your code is super perfect but there is a case that I didn't mention it before, that the string is not always complete, which means that there might be a missing part of the last pattern and in this case this code alone will fail, but anyway I will start now from there, I'm sure it would be much easier now, thanks a lot.

Comment: That makes it easier - you can remove the initial `continue` check and `.slice` the `.repeat` call before comparing it against the input, see edit

Comment: Damn, how do you do that, that's really impressive, is there any place that I can follow you in, like github or codepen, I'm really impressed :)